# How do we check if a gameObject and a linerenderer collide without using unity's built-in physics library?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We have a method to detect if a cannon ball collide with a line rendered turkey object. Basically, we have method to get all of the lines of the turkey in the line rendered. Then we check if distance of the center of the cannon ball to the lines is less than the radius of the cannon ball.

[image]
Here is the code:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class canonTrajectory : MonoBehaviour
    {
        GameObject[] turkeyList = new GameObject[5];
        GameObject turkeys;

        public static float rotationAngle;
        float createdTime;
        float speed = 150f;
        float gravity = -200.0f;
        public GameObject turkey;
        static int NUM_PARTICLES = 26;
        Vector3[] m_position = new Vector3[NUM_PARTICLES];
        LineRenderer lineRenderer;


        void Start()
        {
            turkeys = GameObject.Find("Turkeys");
            for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            {
                turkeyList[i] = turkeys.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            }
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float directionx = Mathf.Cos(-rotationAngle*2.0f*Mathf.PI/360.0f);
            float directiony = Mathf.Sin(-rotationAngle * 2.0f * Mathf.PI / 360.0f);
            Debug.Log(-rotationAngle * 2.0f * Mathf.PI / 360.0f);
            float directionVectorLength = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Pow(directionx, 2) + Mathf.Pow(directiony, 2), (0.5f));
            transform.Translate(-5 * directionx, 5 * directiony , 0.0f);

            if (transform.position.x < -300)
                Destroy(gameObject);

            if (transform.position.y < -77)
                Destroy(gameObject);
            CheckForTouchingTurkey();

        }
        public bool CheckForTouchingTurkey()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < turkeyList.Length; i++)
            {
                Vector2 [] temporaryTurkeyLines = turkeyList[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MoveTurkey>().GetSlopeAndIntercept();
                for (int j = 0; j < temporaryTurkeyLines.Length;j++)
                {
                    float distance = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x * temporaryTurkeyLines[i].x -transform.position.y + temporaryTurkeyLines[i].y) / Mathf.Sqrt(1 + Mathf.Pow(temporaryTurkeyLines[i].x, 2.0f));
                    Debug.Log("distance between ball and turkey is:" + distance);
                    if (distance < 2.5f)
                    {
                        turkeyList[i].gameObject.GetComponent<MoveTurkey>().UpdateMPosition(-20f);
                        Destroy(gameObject);
                    }

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The Turkey movement script:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class MoveTurkey : MonoBehaviour
    {
        LineRenderer lineRenderer;    
        static int NUM_PARTICLES = 26;
        float fTimeStep;
        Vector3[] m_position = new Vector3[NUM_PARTICLES];
        Vector3[] m_acceleration = new Vector3[NUM_PARTICLES];
        Vector3[] m_oldPosition = new Vector3[NUM_PARTICLES];
        Vector2[] slopeAndIntercept = new Vector2[NUM_PARTICLES - 1];
        public Transform fireball;
        float gravity = -9.8f;


        // Start is called before the first frame update
        public void UpdateMPosition(float x)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m_position.Length; i++)
                m_position[i].x +=x;
        }

        public Vector2[] GetSlopeAndIntercept()
        {
            return slopeAndIntercept;
        }

        void Start()
        {
            fTimeStep = 0.5f;

            lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

            lineRenderer.GetPositions(m_position);

            for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
            {
                m_acceleration[i] = new Vector3(0.0f, gravity, 0.0f);
            }
        }

        // Verlet integration step void ParticleSystem::
        void Verlet()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++)
            {
                m_position[i] = 2 * m_position[i] - m_oldPosition[i] + m_acceleration[i] * fTimeStep * fTimeStep;
                m_oldPosition[i] = m_position[i];
            }
        }


        public void FindLinesOfTurkey()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < slopeAndIntercept.Length; i++)
            {
                float slope = (m_position[i + 1].y - m_position[i].y) / (m_position[i + 1].x - m_position[i].x);
                float intercept = m_position[i].y - slope * m_position[i].x;
                slopeAndIntercept[i].x = slope;
                slopeAndIntercept[i].y = intercept;
            }
        }



        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

            //Codes for when the Turkey do the random jump
            int rn_generator = Random.Range(0, 2000);
            if (rn_generator < 5 && m_position[17].y<=-255f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
                    m_acceleration[i].y = 6.0f; //m_acceleration[i].y;
            }

            if(m_position[13].y> 90.0f && m_acceleration[13].y>0.0f)
                for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
                    m_acceleration[i].y = -9.8f; //m_acceleration[i].y;


            //call verlet
            Verlet();
            FindLinesOfTurkey();



            //check proper orientation of the Turkey( turned left or right)
            if (m_position[4].x < m_position[13].x && m_acceleration[25].x >= 0)
            {
                Vector3 sumOfPoints = new Vector3();
                Vector3 sumOfPointsOld = new Vector3();
                int numberOfPointsAdded = 0;
                Vector3 centerOfTurkey = new Vector3();
                Vector3 centerOfTurkeyOld = new Vector3();

                for (int i = 8; i < m_position.Length; i++)
                {
                    sumOfPoints.x += m_position[i].x;
                    sumOfPointsOld.x += m_oldPosition[i].x;
                    numberOfPointsAdded++;
                }

                centerOfTurkey.x = sumOfPoints.x / numberOfPointsAdded;
                centerOfTurkeyOld.x = sumOfPointsOld.x / numberOfPointsAdded;
                for (int i = 0; i < m_position.Length; i++)
                {
                    m_position[i].x = (centerOfTurkey.x + centerOfTurkey.x - m_position[i].x);
                    m_oldPosition[i].x = (centerOfTurkeyOld.x + centerOfTurkeyOld.x - m_oldPosition[i].x);
                }
            }
            else if (m_position[4].x > m_position[13].x && m_acceleration[25].x < 0)
            {
                Vector3 sumOfPoints = new Vector3();
                Vector3 sumOfPointsOld = new Vector3();
                int numberOfPointsAdded = 0;
                Vector3 centerOfTurkey = new Vector3();
                Vector3 centerOfTurkeyOld = new Vector3();

                for (int i = 8; i < m_position.Length; i++)
                {
                    sumOfPoints.x += m_position[i].x;
                    sumOfPointsOld.x += m_oldPosition[i].x;
                    numberOfPointsAdded++;
                }
                centerOfTurkey.x = sumOfPoints.x / numberOfPointsAdded;
                centerOfTurkeyOld.x = sumOfPointsOld.x / numberOfPointsAdded;

                for (int i = 0; i < m_position.Length; i++)
                {
                    m_position[i].x = (centerOfTurkey.x + centerOfTurkey.x - m_position[i].x);
                    m_oldPosition[i].x = (centerOfTurkeyOld.x + centerOfTurkeyOld.x - m_oldPosition[i].x);
                }
            }
            else
               Debug.Log("Nothing");


            //if the turkey is on the ground , remove gravity
            if (m_position[17].y <= -255 && m_position[22].y <= -255)
            {
                float rdGenerator = Random.Range(0.0f, 1.0f);
                if (rdGenerator > 0.5f)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (m_acceleration[25].x == 0)
                            m_acceleration[i].x = 3.0f;
                        m_acceleration[i].y = 0.0f; 

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (m_acceleration[25].x == 0)
                            m_acceleration[i].x = -3.0f;
                        m_acceleration[i].y = 0.0f; 
                    }
                }
            }

            // change direction of turkey when they hit the wall or the mountain
            if (m_position[13].x >= 280)
            {        
                for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
                    m_acceleration[i].x = -2.0f;   
            }

            if (m_position[4].x <= -90)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < m_acceleration.Length; i++)
                    m_acceleration[i].x = 2.0f;
            }

            //draw the turkey
            lineRenderer.SetPositions(m_position);
        }

    }
```

But the code doesn't work. The cannon ball goes through the turkey as if they were not there.

Comment: I'm curious about how you are computing the distance between the two points, from the logs those distances do not look right to me. The straightforward way to compute the distance would have been `new Vector2(temporaryTurkeyLines[i].x - transform.position.x, temporaryTurkeyLines[i].y - transform.position.y).magnitude`.

Comment: Why you dont want to use Unitys built in physics library? this can be easily solved by it

Comment: I cannot use physics library for this homework. Also, the coordinate of the turkey is not global. Also, slopeAndIntercept[i].x is the slope of the ith  line (which draws the turkey) and slopeAndIntercept[i].y is the y-intercept of the ith line(which draws the turkey) .

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for distance from the center of each turkey, factoring the radiuses of turkey + cannonball.

```cs
Vector2 ballPos = cannonball.transform.position;
float turkeyRadius = 0.5f; // we'll assume it has a circle as a hitbox/collider
float cannonBallRadius = 0.1f; // same for the cannonball

// We want the added radius squared, because we wanna compare with sqrMagnitude later.
float minDifToCollide = Mathf.Pow(cannonBallRadius + turkeyRadius, 2);

foreach (var turkey in allTurkeys) {
    Vector2 turkeyPos = turkey.GetCenter();

    // .sqrMagnitude is more performant than .magnitude, so we use that.
    float dif = (turkeyPos - ballPos).sqrMagnitude;
    // Check for collision. 
    if (dif <= minDifToCollide) { CollideWith(turkey); }
}
```

you can add this piece of code to your turkeys so you can visualize their radius:

```cs
public float Radius;

void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.color = Color.teal;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, Radius);
}
```

Comment: Note: it is important to use Vector2 in this case, as you don't want the Z axis to play any part on the magnitude.

Comment: Thank you, But I use the lines of the turkey for collision detection instead of minimum bounding circle.  Also, doesn't two circles collide if distance between their center is less than or equals to sum of their radius iff square of the distance of their center is less than or equals to square of the sum of their radius?